# Google App Engine with Hydra Docker image and Cloud SQL Proxy not working

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, hydra

I am through all the Google keyword variations and read every tutorial and guide twice. Can't get my problem solved.

I have the following setup:

- Google App Engine (flexible)
- Google Cloud SQL (using PostgreSQL)
- Cloud Proxy installed and working locally when connecting with psql

### The Problem

As soon as I am deploying Hydro to my app engine instance, I will get the error message log and error:

```
level=info msg="Connecting with postgres://*:*@/cloudsql/myProjectID:us-central1:myCloudSQLInstance/.s.PGSQL.5432/postgres?sslmode=disable"
level=error msg="An error occurred" error="Could not Connect to SQL: dial tcp [::1]:5432: getsockopt: connection refused"
```

When I am deploying Hydra, the socket is available in the `/cloudsql/myProjectID:us-central1:myCloudSQLInstance` folder with the name `.s.PGSQL.5432`. I also get the message, that the socket is listening `/cloudsql/myProjectID:us-central1:myCloudSQLInstance/.s.PGSQL.5432` when I am using `docker logs myDockerImage`. In another thread I read that this configuration could work. I also tried `/cloudsql/myProjectID:us-central1:myCloudSQLInstance:5432` and even without the port.

It seems like the Hydra container can't get through to the Cloud SQL socket in another container (which is automatically published through app engine). I can also say, that it's not a problem that the socket needs time to warm up. Even after minutes I get the same error logs. And in the end, the whole instance crashes because of an fatal error (with the same error message)

Testing it locally I start the proxy like this: (case 1)

```
cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances=myProjectID:us-central1:myCloudSQLInstance=tcp:5433
```

I also tried: (case 2)

```
cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances=myProjectID:us-central1:myCloudSQLInstance=tcp:0.0.0.0:5433
```

In both cases I changed the database url, for example:

```
docker run -d --name hydra --network host -p 9000:4444 
-e SYSTEM_SECRET=my_long_secret
-e DATABASE_URL=postgres://myUser:myPassword@127.0.0.1:5433/postgres?sslmode=disable 
-e OAUTH2_ISSUER_URL=https://localhost:9000/ 
-e OAUTH2_CONSENT_URL=http://localhost:9020/consent 
-e OAUTH2_LOGIN_URL=http://localhost:9020/login oryd/hydra:latest serve
```

This would be for case 1. But with both configuration it fails and the container crashes after some minutes like on app engine. I also tried using `ipconfig` and got the up of `10.0.75.1`. Ping from inside the Hydra container to that IP is possible.

But when I am using `psql` locally like this:

```
psql "host=127.0.0.1 port=5433 sslmode=disable dbname=myDatabase user=myDBUser"
```

With that command, I can connect to the proxy and to the Cloud SQL database.

Oh and Google SQL Admin API is activated and working.

This is my **app.yaml** for Google App Engine:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 2
  disk_size_gb: 10
env_variables:
  DATABASE_URL: "postgres://myuser:mypass@/cloudsql/myProjectID:us-central1:myCloudSQLInstance/.s.PGSQL.5432?sslmode=disable"
  SYSTEM_SECRET: "my_long_secret"
  OAUTH2_ISSUER_URL: "https://myAuth.appspot.com/"
  OAUTH2_CONSENT_URL: "http://example.com/consent"
  OAUTH2_LOGIN_URL: "http://example.com/login"
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: "myProjectID:us-central1:myCloudSQLInstance"
```

So my question is, is there some configuration that is needed to connect to the Google Cloud SQL Proxy with docker? Maybe there is something in the databse string that I am missing.  It's really hard to debug, as there is just the error message of `connection refused`.

### Update 06/29/2018

It works now on my local machine.

I used the following command to start the docker image for the Cloud SQL proxy:

```
docker run -d --name cloudsql -v c:\Users\myWindowsUser\Desktop\auth\cloudproxy:/cloudsql 
-v c:\Users\myWindowsUser\auth\cloudproxy\config:/config 
-p 127.0.0.1:3307:3307 gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11 
/cloud_sql_proxy 
-instances=myProjectID:us-central1:myCloudSQLInstance=tcp:0.0.0.0:3307 
-credential_file=/config/my-auth.json
```

On Windows you need to check C: (in my case) in Settings/Shared Drives.

And then `postgres://myUser:myPassword@0.0.0.0:3307/postgres?sslmode=disable` as the `DATABASE_URL`.

Now I just need to know how to get it work on Google App Engine. I'll keep you updated!

### UPDATE 2:

Got it working.

I had two problems:

- UNIX Socket was not reachable
- Database sting was TCP based

### The solution

```
docker run -d --name hydra --network host --volume=/cloudsql:/cloudsql 
-p 9000:4444 -e SYSTEM_SECRET=my_long_secret
-e DATABASE_URL=postgres:///myDatabase?host\=/cloudsql/myProjectID:us-central1:myCloudSQLInstance/\&sslmode=disable\&user=myDBUser\&password=myPassword 
-e OAUTH2_ISSUER_URL=https://localhost:9000/ 
-e OAUTH2_CONSENT_URL=http://localhost:9020/consent 
-e OAUTH2_LOGIN_URL=http://localhost:9020/login oryd/hydra:latest serve
```

With that configuration for hydra I was able to connect to the Cloud SQL database. Maybe this helps someone. So problem solved :)!

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it. Seemed complicated!